# Búsqueda de archivos en Windows con fechas por nombre

Tags: windows, busqueda

Estoy intentando crear una expresión regular para hacer búsquedas de archivos en Windows 10. Los archivos estan nombrados con fechas, con estructura, DD-MM-YYYY o DD-MM-YY y extensión pdf. Hay veces que no sólo llevan la fecha si no que algunos archivos llevan también palabras delante o el numero de la versión detrás entre paréntensis.

Ejemplos de tipos de nombres:
`palabra 1-1-2020` // `1-1-2020` // `1-1-2020(2)` //`palabra 1-1-20`//`1-1-20`// `1-1-20(2)`

Quiero encontrar todos los archivos que pertenecen a varios meses.
He probado la siguiente expresión en el buscador de Windows y no entiendo por qué no funciona:

Con esta no encuentra nada.

```
nombre: ~"*-1-*" OR ~"*-2-*" OR ~"*-3-*"
```

Sin embargo esta sí funciona:

```
nombre: ~"*-1-*" OR ~"*-2-*"
```

Me gustaría saber qué estoy haciendo mal al concatenar más de un OR en las búsquedas.